# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in Angular 10

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, upgrade, angular10

I started upgrade from Angular 5 to Angular 10. Now upgraded till Angular 10 but When I'm running ng serve command then getting below error. I have already tried below two commands
'npm cache verify' then deleting node module folder then 'npm install'

Errors:

ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/dist/cpexcel.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './cptable' in 'D:\PD\service\angular\node_modules\xlsx-style\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\PD\service\angular\node_modules\xlsx-style'
ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\PD\service\angular\node_modules\xlsx-style'

These errors was coming after upgrade from Angular 5 to 6 as well.

Please help me how i can solve this ?

Thanks

node version : 10.13.0
npm version: 6.4.1
rxjs :6.6.7
typescript:3.9.2

Already tried solutions but not working :

1. node: {
   fs: "empty"
   } in webpack.config.js
2. "browser": {
   "fs": false,
   "os": false,
   "path": false
   } in package.json

Already tried solutions but not working :

1. node: {
   fs: "empty"
   } in webpack.config.js
2. "browser": {
   "fs": false,
   "os": false,
   "path": false
   } in package.json